# PHP: namespace and dependency injection (slim framework)

Tags: php, dependency-injection, slim

in dependencies, I add the authenticator class to the container:

```
$container['authenticator']=function ($c) {
    return new \App\Auth\LDAPAuthenticator(...);
};
```

But then when I try to use it from the class App\Model\Login it searches the App\Model path. How is this possible?

constructor of App\Model\Login:

```
namespace App\Model;
...

$this->authenticator = $c['authenticator'];
```

Method in App\Model\Login:

```
$result = $this->authenticator($args);
```

Error message:

```
"Call to undefined method App\\Model\\Login::authenticator()
```

Where it should have tried to call App\Auth\LDAPAuthenticator

some clarifications, 
1) this works:

```
$authenticator = new \App\Auth\LDAPAuthenticator(...)
```

2) the LDAPAuthenticator class is callable as it has an __invoke method

Comment: You don't have `authenticator` method in your class. You have `authenticator` property which holds a function.

Comment: `$this->authenticator($args);` this is wrong, you may want `$this->authenticator->authenticator($args);`

Comment: the authenticator class  has an __invoke method, so it's callable without specifying a method. If I call it directly without DI it works.

Comment: The syntax `$o->m()` says *call method `m` of `$o`*. But `m` here isn't a method of the class, it's an anonymous function stored as a property. The `$o->m()` syntax doesn't consider this.

Comment: @deceze, please read my comment. The class is callable.

Comment: So, it should be `($o->m)()`

Comment: @sivann "The class" meaning `App\Model\Login`…?

Comment: @deceze no, LDAPAuthenticator

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't matter. Did you see the duplicate?

Comment: @deceze, yes but I don't see how it is related. Calling the method directly works, it's obvious by the error that this is a namespace issue.

Comment: Just enclose in brackets, is it so __hard__ to do? `$result = ($this->authenticator)($args);`

Comment: @u_mulder It worked! Why? (please add an answer so I can accept)

Comment: __BECAUSE IT IS EXPLAINED IN A DUPE__

Comment: …and in my comment above.

Comment: Thank you guys, the explanation in the dupe was too hard for me to see the relation.